# how to set up proxy for ubuntu on ssh with private key file

Tags: networking, apt, server, updates, amazon-ec2

i have an ec2 instance with ubuntu 22.04 and i connected with ssh using the password file but i need to set up the proxy in order to use sudo apt update, how can i set this up if my password is a ppk file used in putty?